# How to chain BiFunctions?

Tags: java, functional-programming, java-8

I would like to chain BiFunctions, like in the method `chainWanted` in the code sample below.

BiFunction takes Function as a parameter of AndThen. is it possible to somehow chain BiFunctions ?

The code here doesn't compile because of this and I cannot cast BiFunction to Function.

```
import java.util.function.BiFunction;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;

public class Wf {

    BiFunction<RemoteWebDriver, WfParams, RemoteWebDriver> init = this::init;
    BiFunction<RemoteWebDriver, WfParams, RemoteWebDriver> wait = this::wait;

    BiFunction<RemoteWebDriver, WfParams, RemoteWebDriver> chainNow = init
            .andThen(d -> {
                System.out.println("--------------");
                return null;
            });

    BiFunction<RemoteWebDriver, WfParams, RemoteWebDriver> chainWanted = init
            .andThen((BiFunction) wait);

    public RemoteWebDriver init(RemoteWebDriver d, WfParams params) {
        System.out.println("init(d, params)");
        return d;
    }

    public RemoteWebDriver wait(RemoteWebDriver d, WfParams params) {
        System.out.println("Wf.wait(d, params)");
        return d;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Wf().start();
    }

    private void start() {
        chainNow.apply(null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you can chain bifunctions to start with; the result of a bifunction is a single argument, how do you intend to chain it into another one?

Answer (score 6):

Chaining of one `Function` to another works naturally because the return value of the first function is passed as the argument to the next function, and that function's return value is passed as the argument to the subsequent function, and so forth. This doesn't work naturally with `BiFunction` because they take two arguments. The first argument would be the return value from the previous function, but what would the second argument be? It also explains why `BiFunction` allows chaining with `andThen` to a `Function` instead of to another `BiFunction`.

This suggests, however, that it would be possible to chain one `BiFunction` to another if there were some way of providing the value for second argument. This can be done by creating a helper function that stores the value for the second argument in a local variable. Then, a `BiFunction` can be converted into a `Function` by capturing that local variable from the environment and using it as the second argument.

Here's what that would look like.

```
BiFunction<RemoteWebDriver, WfParams, RemoteWebDriver> chainWanted = this::chainHelper;

RemoteWebDriver chainHelper(RemoteWebDriver driver, WfParams params) {
    return
        init.andThen(rwd -> wait.apply(rwd, params))
            .apply(driver, params);
}

// ...

chainWanted.apply(driver, params);
```

The `chainHelper` method holds the `params` argument for later capture. We call `init.andThen()` in order to do the chaining. But this requires a `Function` whereas `wait` is a `BiFunction`. Instead of using a method reference `this::wait` we use the lambda expression

```
rwd -> wait.apply(rwd, params)
```

which captures `params` from the lexical environment. This gives a lambda expression that takes a single argument and returns a single value, so it's now a `Function` that wraps the `wait` which is a `BiFunction`. This is an example of *partial application* or *currying*. Finally, we call the resulting `BiFunction` using `apply()`, passing the original arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Where should the WfParams come from for the invocation of `wait`?  If you mean to reuse the same WfParams for all the functions calls, just put WfParams as a class member variable instead of passing it to each function.

```
class Wf {
    private final WfParams params;

    public Wf(WfParams params) {
        this.params = params;
    }

    UnaryOperator<RemoteWebDriver> init = this::init;
    UnaryOperator<RemoteWebDriver> wait = this::wait;

    Function<RemoteWebDriver,RemoteWebDriver> chain = init.andThen(wait);

    RemoteWebDriver init(RemoteWebDriver d) {
        // can use WfParams here
        return d;
    }

    RemoteWebDriver wait(RemoteWebDriver d) {
        // can use WfParams here            
        return d;
    }

    private void start() {
        chain.apply(null);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Wf(new WfParams()).start();
    }   
}
```

Is there a particular reason you want to use function chaining like that?  Why not simply call `init(...); wait(...);` from `start()`?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this - created my custom BiFunction.
The idea being:

1. Return type is same as the second argument
2. First argument is passed internally to chained biFunction

   ```
   public interface BiFunctionCustom<T, U> extends BiFunction<T,U,U> {

     default BiFunctionCustom<T, U> andThen(BiFunctionCustom<T, U> after) {
         Objects.requireNonNull(after);
         return (T t, U u) -> after.apply(t, apply(t, u));
     }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Event though it doesn't seems like a usual chaining but I came to the following approach, conceptually similar with the one proposed by Stuart Marks :

```
BiFunction<Param1, Param2, Param1> firstBiFunc = (p1, p2) -> {
    // DO SOME STUFF
    return secondBiFunc.apply(p1, p2);
};
BiFunction<Param1, Param2, Param1> secondBiFunc = (p1, p2) -> {
    // DO SOME STUFF
    return p1
};
```